# Move ubuntu yii project to windows platform

Tags: php, yii

I have developed a `yii` project in `ubuntu 12.04`,now i need this project in a windows machine. I have installed `yii` in windows machine,

Now how to run this `ubuntu yii` project in windows machine?

please help me,

thanx in advace.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem. You need Apache and PHP and MySQL. Use some solution like:

https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

And how you developed YII project on ubuntu?... I am really don't understand